# excel formula or vba to repeat number x amount of times

Tags: excel, vba

Maybe a basic question but I am trying to come up with a formula that will repeat a number a certain amount of times, then add 1 to that value and do the same.  In this case I would start at 1, repeat that 6 times, then add 1 and repeat that value (2) 6 times and so on.  End result would look like this:

```
1
1
1
1
1
1
2
2
2
2
2
2
3
3
3
3
3
3
```

Comment: Where do you want the numbers output?

Comment: just in the next column, they output will be added to text to create a series of unique item numbers (shortsleeve1, shortsleeve2, etc.)

Answer (score 5):

Put this in the first cell:

```
=INT((ROW(1:1)-1)/6)+1
```

Then copy down as far as you want.

The `+1` is the starting digit.

The `/6` is the number of times to repeat.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use this formula on the column you wish to number. You can change 6 for any number you want for the repetitions.

`=INT((ROW()+6)/6)`